# Check if URL contains certain word php wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show only posts that contain a certain word in the url. I got this, but it isn't working. I want all the posts that contain blog or news in the url.

```
    <?php 
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

$isItBlog = strpos($url, 'scotch');
$isItNews = strpos($url, 'soda');

if ($isItBlog!==false)
{ 
?>
<h1 class="cat">Worked with - </h1>
               <h1 class="entry-title"><a title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'compass' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"> <?php the_title(); ?>
               </a></h1>
               <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'category-thumb'); ?>
               <div class="entry-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>


<?php
}
if ($isItNews!==false)
{
?>
     <h1 class="entry-title"><a title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'compass' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"> <?php the_title(); ?>
               </a></h1>
               <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'category-thumb'); ?>
               <div class="entry-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

<?php } ?>
       </article>
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this best solution.

> ```
>  $url = 'http://terra.com.br/soda';
>
>  if(strpos($url, 'scotch') == true){
>
>    $value = 'scotch';
>
>  } else if (strpos($url, 'soda') == true){
>
>   $value = 'soda';
>
>  } else {
>
>    $value = 'error';
>
> }
>
> echo $value;
> ```